# Part of the code is non-reachable after using c# await

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous, async-await

I'm writing the video converting tool for one web site.

Logic is next

- User upload the file
- System conver it for user (of course user should not wait while converting)

I have a code:

```
public async void AddVideo(HotelVideosViewModel model)
        {
            var sourceFile = FileHandler.SaveFile(model.VideoFile);
            var fullFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(sourceFile);

            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => video.Convert(fullFilePath));

            model.FileLocation = sourceFile;
            model.IsConverted = true;
            this.Add<HotelVideos>(Mapper.Map<HotelVideosViewModel, HotelVideos>(model));
        }
```

This start encoding:

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => video.Convert(fullFilePath));
```

But the code after this is never executed... Does somebody has a solution?

PS: under video.Conver(...) is have something like:

```
public bool Convert(string fileLocation)
{
// do staff
}
```

**--- UPDATE ---**

Just got the interesting thing. If i'm going to exchange `video.Convert(fullFilePath)` to Thread.Sleep(2000) everything start to work. So the issue is in Second method i think.

So i'm adding the next file code (draft now):

```
using Softpae.Media;

    /// <summary>
    /// TODO: Update summary.
    /// </summary>
    public class VideoConvertManager
    {
        private readonly Job2Convert jobConverter = new Job2Convert();

        private readonly MediaServer mediaServer = new MediaServer();

        public bool Convert(string fileLocation)
        {
            this.jobConverter.pszSrcFile = fileLocation;
            this.jobConverter.pszDstFile = fileLocation + ".mp4";
            this.jobConverter.pszDstFormat = "mp4";
            this.jobConverter.pszAudioCodec = null;
            this.jobConverter.pszVideoCodec = "h264";

            if (this.mediaServer.ConvertFile(this.jobConverter))
            {
                FileHandler.DeleteFile(fileLocation);
                return true;
            };

            FileHandler.DeleteFile(fileLocation);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: PPS. it's the first time i'm using async/await :)

Comment: await isn't going to return until convert is finished, is convert ever finishing?

Comment: Have you tried this tutorial? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh300224(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: To Frobzig: of course, checked. To cshemby: yes, i did.

Comment: What calls AddVideo?  You generally want to avoid 'async void' except for handlers that require void return type.

Comment: If you change that line from the StartNew to just calling Convert normally, does it work?  How about if you ConfigureAwait(false) the task that comes back?

Comment: What calls AddVideo? - Action in Controller, called using Unity (xml config)

Comment: StartNew to just calling Convert normally. No, await require GetAwaiter method..

Comment: @JamesManning ConfigureAwait(false) - works! Please make an answer, i will confirm this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding ConfigureAwait(false) will keep the continuation from being forced on the request thread

Comment: In ASP.NET, not using `ConfigureAwait(false)` means the continuation will be on the request *context*. But that doesn't mean it has to be the same thread that started the request and it also shouldn't cause this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `AddVideo` return `Task`, and `await` its result before completing the ASP.NET request.

**Update:** DO NOT call `Wait` or other blocking methods on an asynchronous `Task`! [This causes deadlock.](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

You may find [my `async` intro](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.

P.S. `async` doesn't change the way HTTP works. You still only have one response per request. If you want your end user (e.g., browser) to not block, then you'll have to implement some kind of queue system where the browser can start video conversion jobs and be notified of their result (e.g., using SignalR). `async` won't just magically make this happen - it only works within the context of a single request/response pair.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. I've tried to make AddVideo as a Task - the same story. PS. i updated the description

Comment: @EvgeniyLabunskiy: Are you `await`ing it?